# Verifying if expected webpage is loaded using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to verify multiple elements on a webpage to make sure that the correct webpage is loaded. I dont not want to verify using URL, coz when I use a different user to login the URL might change. Also I dont want to verify the page using one unique element on the page Is there a way we can verify a page by checking if multiple elements on the page or is there any other way using page factor to verify the complete webpage.

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I would put some identifier right into the page, perhaps in the page header, in a meta tag, or in a data-xxx attribute of the body etc. This is simple and reliable. Which ID you choose depends on your framework. Perhaps the fully qualified name of a controller class or method?